# Regex doesn't omit quotes when matching text in quotes

Tags: regex, node.js

I'm trying to do a non-greedy capture of text inside double quotation marks with regex in node.js. Most of the Google results say I should use one of these:

```
"(.*?)"
"([^"]*)"
```

I tried both, but my code doesn't remove the quotes. My code looks so:

```
var testStr = '|>  "Song" by "Artist" on "Album" <3';
var regex = /"([^"]*)"/g; // or /"(.*?)"/g
var info = testStr.match(regex);
if (info){
    console.dir(info[0]);
    console.dir(info[1]);
    console.dir(info[2]);
}
```

My output is this:

```
'"Song"'
'"Artist"'
'"Album"'
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`match` method returns an array of just *matches*. See [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match):

> Captured groups are not returned.

A fix is to use `exec`:

```js
var re = /"(.*?)"/g; 
var str = '|>  "Song" by "Artist" on "Album" <3';
 
while ((m = re.exec(str)) !== null) {
    document.getElementById("res").innerHTML += m[1] + "<br />";
}
```

```html
<div id="res"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your regex is looking for, and matching quotes. You can do this to modify the value matched to effectively trim off the quotes.

```
var testStr = '|>  "Song" by "Artist" on "Album" <3';
var regex = /"([^"]*)"/g; // or /"(.*?)"/g
var info = testStr.match(regex).map(function (o) {
  return o.substr(1,o.length-2)
});
if (info){
    console.dir(info[0]);
    console.dir(info[1]);
    console.dir(info[2]);
}
```

Comment: I thought about doing this, but I wanted to do it with just one line of regex.

Comment: @Didericis Why? `match()` is faster, all other things being equal. http://jsperf.com/match-v-while/3. Even if you choose to stick with stribizhev's answer, you can increase the speed by pushing to an array and dumping rather than writing with each iteration. (I did use a 20k~ long hunk of gibberish with randomly quoted strings as the test-case. The string is the same for all four tests)

Comment: I didn't know it was faster. That being said, I still like using just one bit of regex for this. I don't need it to be fast, and I like having everything done in one step instead of two. I won't use use `exec()` when performance is important. Thanks for the info. Do you have a link that explains why it's faster, or do you have a short explanation you could put here?

Answer (score 0):

You can give this a shot. This should include everything in the quotes but not the quotes themselves -

```
/(?<=")[^" ]*(?=")/
```

Comment: This is giving me an "invalid group" error: `var regex = /(?<=")[^" ]*(?=")/;`

Comment: Strange. This worked for me. Looks like the other solutions here are manipulating the string after the RegEx matches what you have, which might not be a bad idea.

Comment: Weird. Double checked it, it's definitely the same as what I have above, and it's not working. Tried it with the `g` flag too, same issue.